# Material Design + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design

I've this problem with Material Design :
When I change $scope value and then re-render ng-repeat, I can't reload Material Design events.
There was the same problem when ng-view change, but I resolve it with :

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $timeout) {
  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      loadHandler();
      componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

I've tried to use componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered(); in Controller code, but with no luck, I can't reload Material events after get new data.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using this? https://material.angularjs.org. I don't know Angular or Material Design so I probably can't offer much help, just thought I'd share the link...

Comment: Hey Tolya, if you want to get back about Matt's question I may be able to offer some assistance. Thanks!